# Determine if C++ application is running as a UWP app in Desktop Bridge (Project Centennial)

Tags: c++, winapi, uwp, desktop-bridge

I've packaged a C++/Win32 application as an *appx* and it runs OK. However, since some paths are unavailable I must somehow determine if the application is running as a packaged UWP application and adapt.

Is there a simple *runtime* check one can do to determine if you are running as a packaged UWP application?

Comment: `GetTokenInformation(, TokenIsAppContainer, )` ?

Comment: See also [Determine if C++ application is running as a UWP app, with legacy support](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52207484/850848#52210994).

Comment: AppContainer and package'd vs not are independent questions. Not all package'd processes run in an AppContainer, and process w/o package identity can run in an appcontainer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a simple runtime check one can do to determine if you are running as a packaged UWP application?

Yes, you can check for package identity via [GetPackageFamilyName function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446603(v=vs.85).aspx)

The value `APPMODEL_ERROR_NO_PACKAGE` is returned if not packaged.

Comment: This is the correct answer. When running under UWP `GetPackageFamilyName` will return `ERROR_SUCCESS` while under Win32 it will return `APPMODEL_ERROR_NO_PACKAGE`, which btw is `15700` (decimal) if you're on an older SDK.

Comment: @c00000fd Thx for your confirmation:)

Comment: how to check the same, but for C#?

Comment: GetPackageFullName is fractionally more efficient than GetPackageFamilyName, but GetCurrentPackageFullName is the best answer for the current process - functionally equivalent but more efficient than GetPackageAnything for the current process

Comment: Note that if the app is an UWP packaged app (installed from MS Store), but the user decides to run the containing .exe file from the command line, `APPMODEL_ERROR_NO_PACKAGE` will be returned. I discovered it here: https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/discussions/1484