# Determine if C# application is running as a UWP app in Desktop Bridge (Project Centennial)

Tags: c#, uwp, runtime, desktop-bridge

How to check if application is running as UWP?

[Almost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39609643/240564), but I need it for C#, not C++.

If I try to get `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` and application is running as Win32 application, it throws exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in applcation.exe Additional information: The process has no
>   package identity. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80073D54) occurred

How can I check type of application without exception?

Comment: There just isn't any way that you can't know when you sit in front of your machine.  You have to pick the right project template, maybe enable the desktop bridge, upload the app to the store.  An obvious thing to do, while you sit in front of that machine, is to edit Project > Properties > Build tab > Conditional compilation symbols setting.

Comment: @HansPassant, actually, what I'm trying to do: [almost the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609643/determine-if-c-application-is-running-as-a-uwp-app-in-desktop-bridge-project) but only for C#

Comment: Be sure to not mention that you use the bridge at all, you don't want to make it easy for anybody to help you.

Comment: @HansPassant, changed title and added tag

Comment: You can P/Invoke the API listed in the related question.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT, but, there is no way to use .NET way?

Comment: `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` is impossible on win32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this MSDN article?     [Desktop Bridge – Identify the application’s context](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2016/11/03/desktop-bridge-identify-the-applications-context/)

It has a sample that shows how make the app behave differently, depending the running mode (*win32 desktop application or desktop bridge app*).

Comment: from this article: I need to use P/Invoke or use their nuget, which uses P/Invoke, there is not .NET API for this

Comment: No, GetCurrentPackageFullName is an unmanaged method. There is no .NET equivalent. But again, you can use P/Invoke to call it.

Answer (score 5):

You can call the `GetCurrentPackageFullName` method in C# using P/Invoke. There is a [DesktopBridge.Helpers](https://github.com/qmatteoq/DesktopBridgeHelpers) package that you can use to do this for you. It also works on Windows 7.

```
DesktopBridge.Helpers helpers = new DesktopBridge.Helpers(); 
bool isUwp = helpers.IsRunningAsUwp();
```

You can see how it is implemented here if you are interested: https://github.com/qmatteoq/DesktopBridgeHelpers/blob/master/DesktopBridge.Helpers/Helpers.cs

And here is the Nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DesktopBridge.Helpers/

Comment: yes, it's written in this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2016/11/03/desktop-bridge-identify-the-applications-context/), link from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47882955/240564)

Comment: "using this code on Windows 7, Vista or even XP will always return an exception", but we need Win7

Comment: IsRunningAsUwp() returns false on Windows 7 and lower. It doesn't throw. Didn't you try?

Answer (score 0):

I added a nuget reference to the OSVersionHelper package and then used this code to determine if the app was running as a packaged app using Desktop Bridge:

```
bool isRunningAsPackagedApp = OSVersionHelper.WindowsVersionHelper.HasPackageIdentity;
```